# Move file on CLOSE

Tags: linux, bash

I have a process that is continually writing new files to a directory.  When the current file reaches a certain size, it creates a new one with the timestamp.  Like rolling log files, for example.

When the process closes the current file (A) and creates a new one, I would like to move A to a new directory for processing.  I'm not sure of the best way to do this...

I wrote a bash script that runs every few minutes, lists all the files in the dir sorted by time, and moves all but the most recent.  This works, but I can't help but feel like there is a better way, something more event-driven.  I was looking at using inotifywait and capturing the CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE event for the file ...

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What find of filesystem are you writing to?  NTFS?

Comment: inotify seems likely to be the way to go.

Comment: It's an ext4 filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way.  Using incron:

http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en